# Detect server name in PHP

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a number of instances behind a loadbalancer. Is it possible to detect the name of the machine (e.g. ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com) in PHP for debugging? I looked through phpinfo() and it doesn't seem to have any kind of machine specific information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you'll have to use `$host = system("hostname")` or similar as it appears PHP won't provide that info directly.

IP seems a little more involved.  Depends on how they've got things set up but you can try

```
$config = system("ifconfig | grep \"inet addr\"");
preg_match("/(\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,3})/", $config, $matches);
$ip_addr = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Hmmm. I think we are getting closer, but all machines are reporting 'p-aws-img-www-02' as the hostname.

Comment: Is there a way to get the machine's (not the domain's) ip address?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, the public hostname actually doesn't exist anywhere on the server. It's stored in [EC2's metadata](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html), which can be fetched from 169.254.169.254 on any EC2 instance.

```
$hostname = file_get_contents('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname/');
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get hostname by

```
$hostname = shell_exec("curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname");
```

if you want IP Address then use

```
$IpAddress = shell_exec("curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4");
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
$myservername = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is set to the domain name of my website, not the machine name. Because these are load balanced cloud instances I am sure there is a lot of magic happening behind the scenes.